# Rebuilding maven indexes using eclipse makes no progress

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

i am having an issue with maven indexes rebuilding using eclipse. When I start, it just says `Updating index for repository: central|https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2`

But there is no progress, or even error for tens of minutes, or nothing, it just doesn't give me any feedback.

I have also tried with other eclipse instance on my computer and problem was the same.

I am running Eclipse Neon (4.6.0 m1).

Also i Have tried to delete nexus folder from my `org.eclipse.m2e.core` folder in workspace.

Tried with eclipse Kepler on another computer on same network, and there is a progress (gz file being downloaded).

I am also very sure that i don't have proxy or any other limitations on my computer or network.

Comment: Macen central index rebuilding may take quite a while.  The progress is shown in the Progress pane.

Comment: Don't give up searching on stackoverflow.

Comment: I have searched and searched and apparently no one posted an issue where there is literally no progress. It stands still on 0%, there is no indication that any gz is downloading and also, i cant see anything new in logs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rebuilding Maven indexes Stuck at 0%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36087225/rebuilding-maven-indexes-stuck-at-0)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The progress indicator appears not to work. Left mine alone for about 8 minutes and all of a sudden it was done. (During which I had googled and found this question.)

Once it completed, you can see entries under the Global Repositories > central "folder".

[image: completed repository index]

I am using the Eclipse Mars release, btw.

Comment: Thanks man, that did the trick for me as well. Although I had to update the M2e plugin first. I am using Eclipse Neon.

Comment: Sometimes doing nothing is the solution. Badum tsss

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse policy has changed to not rebuild the index now.
When directly modifying pom.xml, it has been changed to be suggested in the form of auto complete.

[image]

https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/914
https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/930

Answer (score 0):

If while the update is taking place you start a maven operation, e.g., Project(right-click), Run, Maven build..., "goals: dependency:validate", a "User Operation is Waiting" popup will show a progress monitor. It will also show your waiting maven operation.
(Offering this because no answer to this question seemed satisfactory, and it still shows up as the first hit when you query "eclipse progress monitor stuck at 0%".)