# Rebuilding Maven indexes Stuck at 0%

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I am trying to [rebuild the Maven index in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26350902/3357935), but it has been stuck at 0% for hours.

I can't find any results when trying to add dependencies. I have tried running Eclipse as an Administrator and ticking "update repositories" on startup, but neither option worked.

I am using Windows 8.1 Enterprise Edition

[image: Rebuilding Indexes: (0%)]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Leave Eclipse
2. Go to [your-workspace-folder]
3. Remove .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core/nexus
4. Remove .metadata/.plugins/org.maven.ide.eclipse/nexus
5. Restart Eclipse

If it does not help, try also

6. remove [your-home-folder]/.m2/repository/.cache/m2e/${m2e.version}.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/16444984/2886891

---

To **prevent** the impact of various bugs from the m2e plugin, I prefer using always the *external* maven (you have to have it [installed](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/) of course):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Do this, just as [Honza Zidek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36087538/7478890) did:

1. Leave Eclipse
2. Go to [your-workspace-folder]
3. Remove .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core/nexus
4. Remove .metadata/.plugins/org.maven.ide.eclipse/nexus
5. Restart Eclipse
6. remove [your-home-folder]/.m2/repository/.cache/m2e.

Click Window -> Show view -> Other -> Maven Repositories
In the appeared tab click Global Repositories. Right click on central -> Rebuild Index.

It took me 30 minutes to rebuild it. All the time **Progress bar was 0%**. Eclipse downloaded about 10Gb in [your-home-folder]/.m2/repository folder. Then it deleted 8Gb.

To check if download is going, just refresh C drive (or the drive .m2 folder is loceted).